# how to get the jquery-made element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the element by id, than i will give it some elements. However, i cannot get the element that it is made from jquery.

the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    d = $(document.createElement('div'));
        d.id = "go";
        $(d).addClass('class')
            .append("<h2>click button</h2>")
            .appendTo($("#aaa"))
        console.log("div d.id=    "+ d.id);
  })
  function go() {
    var go = $("#go");
     console.log("go()   go.id=  "+ go.id); //undefined
  }
```

my html:

```
 <div id="aaa"></div>
<button onclick="go()">gogogo</button>
```

I got an undefined if i use `var d = $("#go");`. or

I got `null` if i use `var d = document.getElementById('go');`

How to get that element than change its `"<h2>click button</h2>"` to `"<h2>button is clicked!!!</h2>"`?

**UPDATE  1!!**

[image]

the console:

[image]

**UPDATE   2  !!**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    d = $(document.createElement('div'));
        d.id = "go";
        $(d).addClass('post')
            .append("<h2>click button</h2>")
            .appendTo($("#aaa"))
        console.log(" div d.id=    "+ d.id);


    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").hide("slow", function(){ // success to hide it
            alert("The div is now hidden");
        });
    });
  })
  function go() {
    var go = $("#go");
    console.log("go()   go.id=  "+ go.attr('id')); 
  }
```

Comment: did you check your element created ?

Comment: @uzaif it is created!

Comment: element created with go id?

Comment: @uzaif please check my update:)

Comment: when you look at the dev tools do you see this div?

Comment: @uzaif please check my update 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign `d` to a jQuery object not a Div element, if you want to set an attribute of an element inside a jquery object, you would use `.attr`

```
d = $(document.createElement('div'));
d.attr('id','go');
```

or not wrap it in a jQuery object and set the property as normal

```
d = document.createElement('div');
d.id = 'go';
```

Comment: Done!!!! But i have a question. How to change `"<h2>click button</h2>"` to `"<h2>button is clicked!!!</h2>"`?

Comment: Just select the tag and call .text() , something like `$('h2').text("button is clicked!!!");`